# Validar sesion en hosting gratuito

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, hosting, localhost

presento un problema tengo una app de prueba en xampp funciona a la pereccion , la estoy subiendo a un hosting gratuito y solo tengo problema en el login   si coloco cualquier datos me ingresa y me salen unos errores de que no fue definido algo el el index, es obvio el error por que no ah iniciado sesion, lo que pasa es que no me esta ejecutando el "else" en ese logueo osea si los datos no son correctos mandarlo a login y no lo esta haciendo lo deja entrar a la app y si coloco los datos bien del logueo deja entrar perfectamente  y no salen errores, si coloco datos malos deja entrar y salen errores pero tiene la misma funcionalidad , que sera?

Comment: Comprueba la codificación de caracteres de tu fichero PHP, hubo un hosting que me volvió loco hasta que probé con ANSI. Ya me cuentas qué tal

Comment: Como que la codificacion de caracteres?  Soy novato en php

Comment: Busca en el editor de texto plano en el que escribes el código una opción llamada Codificación que te dará varias opciones: ANSI, UTF8 sin BOM, UTF8, ... También te dará esa opción al hacer Guardar como...

Comment: Amigo sabes como me avanzo un poco aun me sale errores, pero ya si deja frenado si no tiene permisos, resulta que yo estaba redireccionando con header ("location........  y me salia el error de header, pero en si la redireccion estaba bien me toco poner un script con wondow.location y ahi si realizo la verificacion de logueo mil gracias amigo me ayudaste bastante